# ¿Cómo obtener el parámetro de otra función?

Tags: javascript

Si tengo dos funciones, como podria acceder a los parametros de una funcion desde otra?

```js
function isMe(nombre, arg){
   isMe.called = true;
   return nombre.toUpperCase();
}

isMe("Pedro");


function necesitoArgumentos(){ // Quiero los argumentos de isMe() 
  if(isMe.called) console.log(isMe.arguments[0]) // Sería el nombre.
}

necesitoArgumentos();
```

Como en este ejemplo lo intento, pero no da resultado

Comment: Supongo que quieres hacerlo sin cambiar el código de `isMe`, ¿no?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para lograr lo que tu quieres, podrías solo añadir la linea `isMe.Arguments = arguments;` a tu código justo después de `isMe.called = true;`, te dejo un ejemplo usando tu código:

```js
function isMe(nombre, arg){
    isMe.called = true;
    //Aquí definimos la propiedad 'Arguments' para poder acceder desde otra función.
    isMe.Arguments = arguments;
    return nombre.toUpperCase();
}

isMe('Pedro');

function necesitoArgumentos(){
 if(isMe.called) console.log( isMe.Arguments[0] );
}

necesitoArgumentos();
```

Espero y te funcione.

Answer (score 2):

Buenas noches,

Solo se me ocurre que utilices una *Anonymous Function Expression*

```
var argumentos = function(nombre){
   result = {
             nombre: nombre.toUpperCase(),
             isCalled: true
            }
   return result;
}

var resultado = argumentos("Pedro");

function necesitoArgumentos(){
  if(resultado.isCalled){
      console.log(resultado.nombre);
  }
}

necesitoArgumentos();
```

Espero que te sirva...

Answer (score 1):

Si lo que quieres es los nombres de los parametros de una funcion, en javascript no hay manera de hacerlo por lo que hay que crearlo.

Utiliz esta funcino que lo que hace es convertir la funcion a string y extraer los nombres de los parametros. En el ejemplo se ve como de la funcion miFuncion extrae los nombres de la funcion que son 3: nombre, apellido y edad:

```js
var STRIP_COMMENTS = /((\/\/.*$)|(\/\*[\s\S]*?\*\/))/mg;
var ARGUMENT_NAMES = /([^\s,]+)/g;
function obtenerParametros(func) 
{
  var fnStr = func.toString().replace(STRIP_COMMENTS, '');
  var result = fnStr.slice(fnStr.indexOf('(')+1, fnStr.indexOf(')')).match(ARGUMENT_NAMES);
  if(result === null)
     result = [];
  return result;
}

function miFuncion(nombre, apellido, edad){}

console.log(obtenerParametros(miFuncion));
```

Answer (score 0):

Realmente lo que estás intentando es hacer programación orientada a objetos con js. Esta es una forma de crear objetos en JS en ES5.

Como verás define primero tu estructura de datos. Posteriormente se especifica que al construir el objeto se deberán de llenar los valores a nivel del objeto para que podamos obtenerlos por fuera.

```js
var IsMe = (function () {
    function IsMe(nombre, arg) {
        this.called = true;
        this._nombre = nombre;
        this.arguments = arg;
    }
    return IsMe;
}());
//fin de definición de clase de objeto
function necesitoArgumentos() {
    var isMe = new IsMe("Pedro", ["Morales", "Rubalcava"]);
    if (isMe.called) {
        // Quiero los argumentos de isMe()
        console.log(isMe.arguments[0]); // Sería el nombre.
    }
}

necesitoArgumentos();
```